# Ionic 2 build issue

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, build

I have a ionic 2 issue, I can't build anymore..

Here is the error message :

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/My\ VitalAire.app/My\ VitalAire normal i386
(1 failure)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/ExtranetTeam/extranets%20app/monespace.vitalaire/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,My VitalAire.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,My VitalAire,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/ExtranetTeam/extranets%20app/monespace.vitalaire/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/ExtranetTeam/extranets%20app/monespace.vitalaire/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try "ionic platform remove ios" and "ionic platform add ios"
Or check this out.
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/449#issuecomment-223557733

Answer (score 0):

So I did :

sudo ionic state reset --plugins
sudo ionic platform remove ios
sudo ionic platform add ios

I made sure that xcode was installed

Then I builded it, and it worked !

But the real solver was to reset the plugins I think..